Continue Detecting Input with KeyListener While Typing In a JTextField
I'm currently working on a small utility window for another application and I'm running into the issue that KeyListener input stops detecting input while a user is focused on a JTextField.
I've made a simple example here to showcase this:
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setLayout(null);
f.setSize(500,500);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setVisible(true);

JTextField txt = new JTextField(15);
txt.setSize(100, 30);
f.add(txt);

f.repaint();
f.revalidate();

f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

     @Override
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

     @Override
     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
          System.out.println(KeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
     }

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
            
});

While not focused on the text field, it works as intended, but as soon as you click on the text field the keyPressed method stops being called.
I understand that this is intended behaviour and that this has been answered multiple times on here, but I'm working with multiple text inputs and I'd rather not have to add a document listener to each and every single one. Is there any way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

What is the KeyListener listening for? You appear to be desiring to get keyboard input when the focus is not on a text component, correct? If so, consider using Key Bindings, not a DocumentListener. Regardless, please tell us more about the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're trying to solve this. Otherwise this is likely an XY problem type question.

Also, do you want keyboard focus off of the text component and on to something else? If so, what? Again, the details matter.

I don't want to change keyboard focus at all. I'd just like for KeyListeners in the parent component to keep being active while keyboard focus is on a child component of that component

Again, to answer the question most properly, it would be best to know exactly what behavior you're trying to elicit. Having said that, use of KeyListener is almost always something to avoid. Perhaps you want to a keyboard focus manager to trap all keystrokes to the application? I'm not sure. One way to do this is as shown:
public static final char FIRST_CHAR = ' '; // or whichever char you choose
public static final char LAST_CHAR = '~'; // or whichever char you choose

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setFocusable(true);
JTextField txt = new JTextField(15);
panel.add(txt);
panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));

KeyboardFocusManager kbfm = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
kbfm.addKeyEventDispatcher(new KeyEventDispatcher() {
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED 
                && e.getKeyCode() >= FIRST_CHAR 
                && e.getKeyCode() <= LAST_CHAR){

            // do whatever with the key information here.
            System.out.println("Key pressed: " + e.getKeyChar());
        }

        // Allow event to be redispatched
        return false;
    }
});

JFrame f = new JFrame("Main02");
f.add(panel);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);


That seems to do it. For context, I'm working on a small application to just put some squares onto a jframe and allow you to edit them. I also have a separate edit window that I was using to allow users to change properties of those squares, using JTextFields. What I was trying to do is apply those changes when you press a certain key. Anyway, when paired with a small loop to check that at least one text field is focused, this works amazingly. Thank you!

@ObSp: please edit your original question to show images of the main window as well as the dialog sub-windows. This may make everything clearer and could lead to a better solution.
